# Is there a way to change your cwd in Python using a file as an input?

Tags: python, file, input

I have a Python program where I am calculating the number of files within different directories, but I wanted to know if it was possible to use a text file containing a list of different directory locations to change the cwd within my program?

Input: Would be a text file that has different folder locations that contains various files.

I have my program set up to return the total amount of files in a given folder location and return the amount to a count text file that will be located in each folder the program is called on.

Comment: can you details out more ? what is input and output ?

Comment: `chdir` takes an `str` argument. It doesn't matter where that `str` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os` module in Python.

```
import os

# dirs will store the list of directories, can be populated from your text file
dirs = []

text_file = open(your_text_file, "r")
for dir in text_file.readlines():
    dirs.append(dir)

#Now simply loop over dirs list
for directory in dirs:
    # Change directory
    os.chdir(directory)

    # Print cwd
    print(os.getcwd())

    # Print number of files in cwd
    print(len([name for name in os.listdir(directory)
               if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, name))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
start_dir = os.getcwd()
indexfile = open(dir_index_file, "r")
for targetdir in indexfile.readlines():
    os.chdir(targetdir)
    # Do your stuff here

os.chdir(start_dir)
```

Do bear in mind that if your program dies half way through it'll leave you in a different working directory to the one you started in, which is confusing for users and can occasionally be dangerous (especially if they don't notice it's happened and start trying to delete files that they expect to be there - they might get the wrong file). You might want to consider if there's a way to achieve what you want without changing the working directory.

EDIT:

And to suggest the latter, rather than changing directory use `os.listdir()` to get the files in the directory of interest:

```
import os
start_dir = os.getcwd()
indexfile = open(dir_index_file, "r")
for targetdir in indexfile.readlines():
    contents = os.listdir(targetdir)
    numfiles = len(contents)
    countfile = open(os.path.join(targetdir, "count.txt"), "w")
    countfile.write(str(numfiles))
    countfile.close()
```

Note that this will count files and directories, not just files. If you only want files then you'll have to go through the list returned by `os.listdir` checking whether each item is a file using `os.path.isfile()`

Comment: "if your program dies half way through it'll leave you in a different working directory to the one you started in". This is not true, each process has its own current directory. For example run `sh -c 'cd /etc; ls passwd'` or `python -c 'import os; os.chdir("/etc")'` and you'll notice that your shell's current directory hasn't changed.